# Empty page for the sign-up and sign-in pages hosted by AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have created the user pool and added new users to the user pool. My requirement is to use the default sign up/login page provided by cognito. So after retrieving the domain name for the hosted page it renders an empty page.

[image]

[image]

By simply entering the domain ends in several errors in the console. Appreciate if any one has identified the root cause for this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you simply add a `/login` to your existing URL you'll start to get useful error messages:

https://praedictio.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/login

It's not documented very well, but your URL also requires some parameters:

- `client_id` - relates to the app for the identity provider.
- `redirect_url` - should match your redirect url from the UserPool app settings.
- `response_type` - token (or code).

```
https://praedictio.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=(client_id)&redirect_uri=(encoded uri)
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `scope` parameter in the url, if you enable any scope within app client of cognito user pool.

Comment: Wow you guru - the `/login` thing is a game changer, no idea why they dont give you any error messages without that endpoint

Answer (score 4):

URL should be in the following format:

---

https://**domain**/login?response_type=**code**&client_id=**client_id**&redirect_uri=**your_callback_url**

---

Variables can be found in AWS > Amazon Cognito > User Pool > App Integration Tab

**Domain:**
[image]

**Client ID of the App**
[image]

**Callback URL of the App**
[image]

Pleaser refer [Cognito document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-app-integration.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It has been mentioned in the other 2 answers, the URL is simply missing some parameters. If you do not want to gather and enter these manually, the best way is to launch a test of your hosted ui from the console:

Go to your Cognito User Pool, select the app-client you are interested in, then under Hosted UI, click "View Hosted UI" and copy the url in the newly opened tab
[image: "View Hosted UI" Dialog box]